# Parallel Tasking Concurrency with Dependencies on Python like GNU Make

Tags: python, concurrency, dependencies, makefile, parallel-processing

I'm looking for a method or possibly a philosophical approach for how to do something like GNU Make within python.  Currently, we utilize makefiles to execute processing because the makefiles are extremely good at parallel runs with changing single option: -j x.  In addition, gnu make already has the dependency stacks built into it, so adding a secondary processor or the ability to process more threads just means updating that single option.  I want that same power and flexibility in python, but I don't see it.

As an example:

```
all:  dependency_a dependency_b dependency_c

dependency_a:  dependency_d
    stuff

dependency_b:  dependency_d
    stuff

dependency_c:  dependency_e
    stuff

dependency_d:  dependency_f
    stuff

dependency_e:
    stuff

dependency_f:
    stuff
```

If we do a standard single thread operation (-j 1), the order of operation might be:

```
dependency_f -> dependency_d -> dependency_a -> dependency_b -> dependency_e \
             -> dependency_c
```

For two threads (-j 2), we might see:

```
1: dependency_f -> dependency_d -> dependency_a -> dependency_b

2: dependency_e -> dependency_c
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on either a package already built or an approach?  I'm totally open, provided it's a pythonic solution/approach.

Please and Thanks in advance!

Comment: 2022, and some as still looking for this

Answer (score 3):

You might want to have a look a [jug](https://github.com/luispedro/jug).  It's a task-based parallelisation framework that includes dependency tracking.

Answer (score 1):

Have also a look at [Waf](http://code.google.com/p/waf/), it's less complicated than Scons.

> Waf is a Python-based framework for
>   configuring, compiling and installing
>   applications. Here are perhaps the
>   most important features of Waf:
>
> Automatic build order: the build order
>   is computed from input and output
>   files, among others Automatic
>   dependencies: tasks to execute are
>   detected by hashing files and commands
>   Performance: tasks are executed in
>   parallel automatically Flexibility:
>   new commands can be added very easily
>   through subclassing Features: support
>   for lots of programming languages and
>   compilers is included by default
>   Documentation: the application is
>   based on a robust model documented in
>   The Waf book and in the API docs
>   Python support: from Python 2.4 to 3.2
>   (Jython 2.5 and PyPy are also
>   supported)

(from the website)

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Scons](http://www.scons.org/), as it already does the computations you want, and you can subvert it to do pretty much anything (like Make).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Scons](http://www.scons.org/). It is a replacement for GNU Make written in Python.

> SCons is a software construction
>   tool—that is, a superior alternative
>   to the classic "Make" build tool that
>   we all know and love.
>
> SCons is implemented as a Python
>   script and set of modules, and SCons
>   "configuration files" are actually
>   executed as Python scripts. This gives
>   SCons many powerful capabilities not
>   found in other software build tools.

Answer (score 0):

#### [redo -j](https://github.com/apenwarr/redo#readme)

"Smaller, easier, more powerful, and more reliable than make. An implementation of [djb's redo](http://cr.yp.to/redo.html)" in Python.

Comment: Sadly the project stopped being maintained in 2019 and the issue tracker is disabled.

Comment: @sorin as I understand, there is redo-rs which claims feature parity. I haven't used the project in a while ([`fabric`](https://docs.fabfile.org/en/stable/getting-started.html#addendum-the-fab-command-line-tool) fits better for my project chores/CI/CD tasks)